# ConcurrencyMode.Multiple and WebOperationContext.Current static property

Tags: c#, wcf, concurrency, state, global

I have a WCF service with `ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` option. Can I safely read incoming request HTTP headers and set outgoing response ones considering the fact that service requests are processed concurrently? I doubt because `WebOperationContext.Current` is a global state. Does it check current thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` make sense only if you have instancing which allows sharing the service instance. In case of REST service you most probably doesn't have such instancing (unless you are using singleton service) and you should not have such instancing (because REST service doesn't maintain state - all state is transferred in the request).

REST service uses per request instancing and each request is served by a new thread (from thread pool) and new instance of the service class automatically. You don't need this setting at all.

`WebOperationContext.Current` retrieves current context from private thread static variable inside the context so it is not shared among threads.

Comment: Yes, I can see currentContext private field marked with ThreadStatic attribute in OperationContext class. Thanks Ladislav for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Well, both yes and no.** The [WebOperationContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.weboperationcontext.current.aspx) property is indeed thread safe. However the instance members of the returned [WebOperationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.weboperationcontext.aspx) object are not. That means you'll have to manage synchronization in your service method yourself.

Here's what MSDN says about [ConcurrencyMode.Multiple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.concurrencymode.aspx):

> The service instance is
>   multi-threaded. No synchronization
>   guarantees are made. Because other
>   threads can change your service object
>   at any time, you must handle
>   synchronization and state consistency
>   at all times.

Your service implementation could then look something like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private Object syncObject = new Object();

    public void MyServiceOperation()
    {
        lock (this.syncObject)
        {
            // Service implementation
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, what's about `WebOperationContext.Current`? It should somehow know about the current context. Since it's static, it should dynamically retrieve the context of the current thread I guess.

Comment: @bsnote Correct: the static [WebOperationContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.weboperationcontext.current.aspx) property is thread safe. However the instance members of the [WebOperationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.weboperationcontext.aspx) class are not, so all attempts to manipulate any property on the object from multiple threads could potentially suffer from race conditions. You're better off synchronizing the entire service method implementation to be on the safe side.